# Material does not show when I try to display my x model in a Directx9 program. Can someone help me out?

Tags: export

first question here. Can someone tell me that why my .x model export from Blender won't show the materials in my program coded in DirectX. There's nothing complex about the materials just two solid colors as shown in the picture. Is there a setting that I'm missing from blender? It just looks grey in the actual program. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Did you check the export materials checkbox in the exporter?
You may also want to try with BI materials, the .x exporter is pretty old, and cycles material support may not have been added.

Comment: Also can you check the model in a separate viewer like http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_viewer.html to see if it is your program or not?